# Only MySqlParameter objects may be stored. What does this mean?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I am building a query with some parameters. This query is working fine in my local machine, but the same is not working with my Remote server. Its showing me the following error.

Followings are some code snippet

```
sqlQuery.Append("select a.*,b.Rank from informationposting a, userdetails b where a.StexId=b.StexId and MATCH (a.InfoPost) AGAINST (@search IN BOOLEAN MODE) ");
```

There are couple of more parameters which are added in the following way

```
 if (search.CategoryId != null && search.CategoryId != 0.ToString())
        {
            sqlQuery.Append("AND a.InfoType=@categoryId ");
            var param = new MySqlParameter("@categoryId", MySqlDbType.Int24);
            param.Value = search.CategoryId;
            cParameters.Add(param);

        }
```

and finally the query is executed in the following way.

```
 var listInfo = (search.SearchText == "") ? null : db.InformationPostings
               .SqlQuery(sqlQuery.ToString(), cParameters.ToArray())
               .ToList().ToPagedList(page ?? 1, 10);
```

Can anyone let me know what is the issue?

[image]

Comment: where is the error ?

Comment: @HusseinZawawi - Above is the attached screenshot of the image.

Comment: Try to use ?" instead of "@".

Comment: Nopes, It did not help.. I just want to know why does that error come?